# Regular expression - Find and Replace in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, dreamweaver

I have over a thousand webpages I need to grap html data within a certain field and then not replace that data but I need to copy that data to a meta field above in head of same html document.

I found code below somewhat use full.

find:

`<span class="CatStyle">(.*)</span>`

replace eg.

`<span class="CatStyle">$1</span>
<meta name="Category" content="$1">`

But How would I use / could I use regular expression to find said data above but then instead of replacing like i have in above example, could I replace / insert the var $1 into  `<meta name="Category" content="$1">` within head of document, instead of inserting underneath of span. ?

Any Ideas?

Comment: That sounds like you need to use the pattern inside a search and replace dialog, right? And there is only one `meta` tag with the name `Category` *before* the `span` in question? Try `(<meta name="Category" content=")[^"]*(">[\s\S]*<span class="CatStyle">)([\s\S]*?)(</span>)` and replace with  `$1$3$2$3$4`

Comment: Spot On! Worked Perfectly!  :D Legend.  :)    You should repost this below as an answer, So I can upvote it as correct answer.

Comment: Also when it comes to regular expression I understand as far as A(.*)B finds value  between A & B and makes it $1 for replacement purposes.   How exactly did you work this out  / what is the code / functions doing ? This works perfectly, but I'm just curious about exactly how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE**: To manipulate HTML, you can use better tools - HTML parsers -  than an S&R dialog with regex support.

**For a one-off job**, if you need to use the pattern inside a search and replace dialog *and* there is only one `meta` tag with the `name` equal to *Category* before the `span`, you may use

```
(<meta name="Category" content=")[^"]*(">[\s\S]*<span class="CatStyle">)([\s\S]*?)(</span>)
```

and replace with `$1$3$2$3$4` backreference sequence.

**Details**:

- `(<meta name="Category" content=")` - Group 1 capturing `<meta name="Category" content="` string
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than `"`
- `(">[\s\S]*<span class="CatStyle">)`  - Group 2 capturing `">`, then any 0+ chars (as many as possible) up to the last `<span class="CatStyle">` and then `<span class="CatStyle">` itself
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 3 capturing any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first...
- `(</span>)` - Group 4 capturing `</span>`

The `$n` are backreferences to the groups defined in the pattern with the help of paired `(...)`.

Comment: Also, see more about [*Capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [*Backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) at regular-expressions.info.